# Error: Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'. [macOS Monterey Apple Chip - Android studio]

Tags: android, android-ndk, apple-m1, ndk-build

I am trying to compile project on apple chip M1MAX macOS Monterey. and facing following problem.

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /Users/ahmed/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.10.2.4988404/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a ndpi vpnproxy-jni zdtun}
ninja: Entering directory `/Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a'
[1/189] Building C object build/CMakeFiles/zdtun.dir/utils.c.o
[2/189] Building C object build/CMakeFiles/zdtun.dir/zdtun.c.o
[3/189] Linking C shared library /Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libzdtun.so
[4/189] Generating /Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/submodules/nDPI/src/include/ndpi_api.h
FAILED: /Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/submodules/nDPI/src/include/ndpi_api.h 
cd /Users/ahmed/Downloads/mion-pipeline/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a && cd ../../../../../submodules/nDPI && ./autogen.sh && ./configure --disable-gcrypt
autoconf is missing: please install it and try again
/bin/sh: ./configure: No such file or directory
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```